# Using angular2 services outside of an angular app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I have an angular2 app with services making Http calls to the server api. How can I call just these services in a different app that uses react.js without bootstrapping the angular2 or without using angular components.

```
App1(angular2) -> component1 -> SharedService1(say http api client)
                                 ^ 
                                 |(call service from react to get data)
App2(react)             ->     React Component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new injector with `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and acquire `Http` from it like:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
let http = injector.get(Http);
http.get('http://someurl').subscribe(...)
```